# Storing big data in redux state - 30,000 items

Tags: reactjs, react-native, websocket, redux, bigdata

I currently have a web socket which pushes data in a JsonAPI format to a react-native app, which then places the items in a redux store at intervals.

Works perfectly for 5,000 - 10,000 items. However I need to support around 30,000 items. Each item(object) has on average 12-ish keys.

Currently this crashes the app, either when I normalize parts of the data or merge new chunks of data with existing data already in my store.

Any advice would be really appreciated.

```js
import debounce from 'lodash/debounce'
import merge from 'lodash/merge

let data = {}

const migrateData = () => {
    InteractionManager.runAfterInteractions(() => {
        dispatch(createSocketData(data))
        data = {}
    })
}

const debounced = debounce(migrateData, 3000)

cable.subscriptions.create('SyncChannel', {
    received: (payload) => {
        if(payload.serialized){
            data = merge(data, normalize(payload.serialized))
            debounced()
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not recommend you to store big data in redux store. For now you need to support 30,000 items. Tomorrow you need to support 50,000 items, 100,000 items...

You can try to use storage specific components to solve your problem.
For example i use SQLite3.

[SQLite3 component for react-native support both for IOS and Android](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use Realm.

There sholud be no issues storing 1000 objects in Realm. It has been optimized for storing huge data and only loads data into memory when needed.